# How to use activeTab to avoid extension publishing delays in the Chrome Web Store

Tags: google-chrome-extension, store

I have a chrome extension built for scraping a few particular pages, and then generating docs with that data on screens built into the extension. It requires regular updates. I keep getting the "Publishing will be delayed warning" below when I go to publish in the Chrome Web Store. The message suggests that I use active tab and narrower host permissions even though my manifest contains the following:

```
"permissions": ["storage",
                "declarativeContent",
                "activeTab",
                "downloads"],
"background": {
  "scripts": ["background.js"],
  "persistent": false
},
```

In the background.js, I have a **chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules** statement with the following **chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher** conditions:

```
      pageUrl: {hostContains: ''}
      pageUrl: {hostContains: 'secure.vermont.gov'}
      pageUrl: {urlContains: 'chrome-extension://'}
```

I replaced first one (intended for local files) with codeforbtv.org so there was no wildcard. Nonetheless, I got the same warning in the store.

The only tabs function I use is in the following code:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: 'payload.js' });
```

Payload.js is two lines of code which grabs a large html block and sends it via **chrome.runtime.sendMessage**.

The relevant codebase can be found here in the extensionDirectory folder: https://github.com/codeforbtv/expunge-vt.

The extension can work on the sample HTML files in the sampleDocketHTML folder.

[image: Notice of Publishing Delay]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `hostContains: ''` matches every URL because `''` is present in every string so it's a broad host permission.

   To match local files you can probably use `schemes: ['file']` but that will be still a broad host permission so I guess you'll have to forget about files.
2. `urlContains: 'chrome-extension://'` from the point of view of the web store's automatic detector is also a broad host permission because evidently the script doesn't analyze the pattern so it's considered just a substring match.

   An extension can't work on other extension's pages anyway normally so you probably don't need this.
3. `hostContains: 'secure.vermont.gov'` is also a broad host permission because this pattern is not anchored to the TLD (top-level domain) so it may occur anywhere and thus match totally irrelevant hosts.

   Either use `hostSuffix: '.secure.vermont.gov'` which will also match the dot-less version and any subdomain or `hostEquals`.

Answer (score 1):

The warning is permissions based and is a general warning the review will take longer if you use more sensitive permissions for your extension.
Anecdotally I recently used wildcard host permissions (*://*/*) for a published extension and received the same warning. The review process ended up taking 3 days until it was approved.

You should in general expect longer review times when using sensitive permissions as Google's bandwidth to manually review extensions is currently reduced.